# refresh javascript after load ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, submit, refresh

Good evening,
I am importing with the method load different form which changes when submit, unfortunately the elements are not recorded by javascript after the use of ajax, I found answers to my prolet but I can not remedy it in square...

My test.php file simply returns a text & submite input with a form ^^
Thank you !

```js
$("#voteform").load("test.php", { });
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#vote").submit(function () {
    alert('test');
    $("#voteform").load("test.php", {
       username: $("#username").val()
      });
    return false;
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="fr">
 
 <head>
 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WorldCube.fr || Votes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vote.css">
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 </head>

 <body>
 
  <div class="votesystem center">
   
   <div class="votetitle">
   
   </div>
   
   
   <div id="voteform" class="voteform">
    
   </div>
  
  </div>
 </body>
 
 
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what question you're asking, but if you're saying that your event listeners or selectors aren't working before/due to HTML changes after page load, then you can you a selector like this:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#vote", function(e){
   // your code here
});
```

The difference here is that by applying the listener to the *document* then even after content loads, the event listener will be still work as expected.

You'll want to put this JavaScript code in a place that is loaded with the document only once, maybe initially, so that event listeners aren't attached twice.